# Are Windows password hashes salted with the user name?

Tags: cryptography, passwords, windows

I'll readily admit I'm pretty clueless when it comes to cryptography, so there may already be some false assumptions in the question title itself :-)

Still, I "heard" that it is more secure to store the hashes of the username/password combinations than only the hashes of the passwords. ([Salting?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29))

If so, are windows user passwords stored like this? (And if not, are they stored somehow differently that "only" the password hash?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file containing passwords in Windows clients is called the SAM file. All passwords stored locally in the SAM file (e.g. local accounts) are hashed with a salt.

Active Directory on the other hand will store passwords without a hash, but in a different file on the Domain Controller.  Domain account passwords are stored locally by default for users to be able to sign on when they cannot connect to a DC, and these passwords are hashed with a salt as well.

See here: [Does Windows really still use unsalted MD4 for password storage?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/5071/does-windows-really-still-use-unsalted-md4-for-password-storage)

Comment: I'm still left confused what's with the passwords on my *local PC* (not part of a Domain). Googling for SAM file doesn't really enlighten me. Sorry for being dense here :-)

Comment: @Martin edited... :)

Comment: Thanks! Now I'll be so bold to ask clarification on whether the Salt is the user name (or whether this matters at all)? :-)

Comment: You know, I don't actually know. I would assume it's a randomly generated value, but don't quote me on it. Does it matter? Hard to sayt: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/8015/what-should-be-used-as-a-salt

Comment: I know this was asked 6 years ago! But are you sure that the SAM file is salted? LAN and NTLM is stored in the SAM file and Im sure they are not salted.

Comment: The value used to validate a local offline password is a salted hash. The SAM also includes various other things for caches. Those values are necessarily not hashed, but encrypted. Those cached values generally only apply in domain scenarios.